# Minecraft Sprint Glitch

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I'm sprinting in minecraft. All is fine but when I jump and sprint. My sprint stops in mid air and it makes parkour way harder since I cant sprint and jump more then 2 blocks. Anyone know whats happening? ( My sprint key is W and my Jump is Spacebar )

Comment: Are you holding W while jumping? Releasing it cancels the sprint function.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you release <kbd>W</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (or whatever key you use to sprint) and the space bar after you hit the block you want to jump to. If you release even a little bit off one of those keys, you will stop long-jumping midair. Also make sure you are not "sliding" your finger from one key to the other while hitting either <kbd>W</kbd> or the space bar. Accidentally hitting another key in midair may cancel your jump.

Answer (score 1):

On normal settings, pressing <kbd>W</kbd> one time, releasing it, pressing and holding it will result in your walking with sprint enabled until you release the key.

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (the default sprint key) on the other hand, while held will always put you to sprint mode, even if you loose stamina or release and press <kbd>W</kbd> again while not having had released the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key. You do not need to press <kbd>W</kbd> two times while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

**Your problem might have been the result of setting the walk forward and the sprint key both to** <kbd>W</kbd>. Try setting sprint to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.